# How to delete a loaded database after it's finished

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I use a ajax script with php.

```
<style>
.posts { height: 100%; overflow: auto; width: 100%; }
.loading { color: green; }
#loading { display:none; color:green; font-size:20px; }
</style>
```

index.php

```
<ul id="results"></ul>
<span id="loading">Loading Please wait...</span>
```

javascript

```
$(function() {
   loadResults(0);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if($("#loading").css('display') == 'none') {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
        var limitStart = $("#results li").length;
        loadResults(limitStart); 
        }
      }
    }); 
    function loadResults(limitStart) {
        $("#loading").css('display','block');
        $.ajax({
            url: "fetch.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                limitStart: limitStart
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $("#results").append("<li id='"+key.id+"'>"+value.title+"</li>"); 
                });
                $("#loading").css('display','none');   
            }
        });
    };
});
```

fetch.php

```
$limitStart = $_POST['limitStart'];
$limitCount = 10; 
if(isset($limitStart ) || !empty($limitStart)) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type='post' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limitStart, $limitCount";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$res = array();
    while($resultSet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $res[] = array('id'=>$resultSet['id'],'title'=>$resultSet['title']); 
    }
echo json_encode($res);
}
```

I scroll down,It (Loading Please wait...) shows, but When the database is finished, It (Loading Please wait...) still shows the load.

Comment: Please change `SELECT *` to `SELECT id, title` as a personal favor to me so that you can use `echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));`

Comment: I'd remove the `isset()` condition and rely on `!empty($limitStart)`.

Comment: Are the return results displayed? Do you have any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change SELECT * to SELECT id, title as a personal favor to me so that you can use **echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));**